# I have a Hp mini 200 (I believe) and I tried installing Ubuntu 15.02 on it and after boot it says something about no root

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, system-installation

As in the title when it boots up it brings up a box talking about no root and something about a disk portion that I am needing to change. The way I did the download was I downloaded it via another laptop and then stuck an unzipped copy of it on the flash drive because the Hp couldn't open the Iso or disk file to get to the Ubuntu installer icon. I am currently stuck at the Ubuntu no root, disk portion screen and I do not know what to do. Was I not supposed to install this way? Or is there a way to fix this problem. I'm not much of a computer nerd but I know my way around one fairly well. (In addition before I installed Ubuntu 15.02 the laptop had Windows 7 starter on it. The Ubuntu version was also 32-bit as well because the laptop only has like 1.77-1.78 gigabytes of ram to offer.)

Comment: Please put some effort into your question. What _exactly_ does it say? "Something about no root" is not very informative. Please [edit] your question and explain, clearly, what you did and what the problem is.

Comment: Please follow this tutorial on installing Ubuntu, it will cover adding a root partition http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu

Comment: @markkirby even if iv already started the install that way?

Comment: Start again, follow the instructions